My internal WIFi chip on my HP 650 laptop has failed and I want to use a Wifi dodgle
I recently wiped my laptop and installed Ubuntu 22 having previously been using Ubuntu 22 for a few years. I think the internal wifi module had failed as I was getting "failed to connect to Wifi " messages before the upgrade.
At the moment the new OS is stuck with the old wifi settings and I cant seem to be able to setup the system to ignore the internal Wifi module and use the new one.
I was thinking, what would happen if I did an OS re install with the WIFI dongle attached?


What version did you just install? 2) There is no need to reinstall to plug in a USB wifi adapter.


Are you running Ubuntu Core? That would be what Ubuntu 22 is. If not please edit the question and put in the actual version info.

Install a supported version of Ubuntu such as 22.04 or 24.04. Do not use Ubuntu 22.10. This version has reached the end of life. 22.10 is not supported.

Thanks for the information . In did try to re install Ubuntu 22.04 with the Dongle connected. After several attempts (I double checked that the boot source was the DVD drive with the Ubuntu install disk), it just sat there with the wheel timer going for two hours and no sign of activity. I then tried the SUSE Linux install disk with the  dongle in situ and it seems to have worked! I get internet connectivity via WIFI  and I think it must be using the new wifi dongle!
